# XSL to HTML: How to keep a closing div tag when the inside is empty?

Tags: html, xslt

I am having an issue with XSL transformation. I have a divtag which is sometimes with some data, and sometimes it is empty. Whenever it is empty with no children, I am getting this kind of format:

```
<div class="test" style="display:none" />
```

But I need to have it in this format:

```
<div class="test" style="display:none"></div>
```

XSL template:

```
<div class="test" style="display:none">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="BookType='SciFi'">
            <table class="test" style="display:none">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Books/BookName">
                        <td>
                            <span>
                                <xsl:value-of select="BookName"/>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</div>
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: you can add `<xsl:text></xsl:text>` so you can have <div></div>

Comment: before the opening div tag or after?

Comment: Is your output method set to `html`?

Comment: In addition to the comment by Michael to set `<xsl:output method="html"/>`, make sure for that to result in empty `div` serialization as `<div></div>` that the result elements are in no namespace, or if you have created XHTML, that you then use `method="xhtml"` together with an XSLT 2 or 3 processor.

Comment: @ ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ adding an empty text node to an element should have no effect and should certainly not affect the way the element is serialized. If it does, it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing HTML as output so you should use the HTML output method

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
```

Comment: I've made this, but divs are still like <div/>

Comment: Perhaps you're using the DOM serializer and not the XSLT serializer. You haven't given us much information.